# SwiftUI Picker, converting String to a Double

Tags: double, picker, swiftui

I am playing with SwiftUI and have a Picker selecting some Strings in an Array which are Numbers..
The picker works well and I can display the value on the screen, however I need to be able to set the selected string from the array to a Double.

I'm sure there are some very kind and clever people out there that can help me out..

I would like to set :

var totalFrequency : Double = 0.0

from the two values from the Picker.

Thank you !!!

Craig

```
import SwiftUI

struct DipoleSelect : View {
  @State var mhzValueIndex = 0
  @State var mhzValueStepIndex = 0
  var frequencyValue = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" ]
  var frequencyStep = [".000", ".005", ".010"]
  var totalFrequency : Double = 0.0

  var body: some View {

    VStack {

      Text("Select Frequency")
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .fontWeight(.heavy)
        .padding([.top,], -180.0)

      Picker(selection: $mhzValueIndex, label: Text("")) {
        ForEach(0 ..< frequencyValue.count) {
          Text(self.frequencyValue[$0] + " mhz").font(.largeTitle).fontWeight(.semibold).color(Color.black).tag($0)
        }.font(.title)

      }.padding(.top, -170)

      Picker(selection: $mhzValueStepIndex, label: Text("")) {
        ForEach(0 ..< frequencyStep.count) {
          Text(self.frequencyStep[$0]).tag($0)
        }

      }.padding()

      Text("You Selected \(frequencyValue[mhzValueIndex])\(frequencyStep[mhzValueStepIndex]) Mhz")

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you want? The question is not clear.

Comment: Sorry.. var totalFrequency : Double = 0.0 is wish to set from the two variables being from the Picker.. (frequencyValue[mhzValueIndex]) (frequencyStep[mhzValueStepIndex]) So then each picker shows the values from the array, I show them in the Text and wish to be able to take those numbers from the picker and set it to a Double... For example, one picker displays Numbers 1 to 9 and the other Picker shows Numbers .000, .005, .010... So if the two Pickers select say 7.005 it is a String, however I wish to convert that to a Double.  Hope that makes sense... thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution. Hope it will work for you.

```
final class Property: BindableObject {
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Property, Never>()

    var frequencyValue = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" ]
    var frequencyStep = [".000", ".005", ".010"]

    var mhzValueIndex: Int = 0 {
        didSet{
            totalFrequency = totalFrequency + getDouble(value: frequencyValue[mhzValueIndex])
            didChange.send(self)

        }
    }

    var mhzValueStepIndex: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            totalFrequency = totalFrequency + getDouble(value: frequencyStep[mhzValueStepIndex])
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    var totalFrequency: Double = 0.0 {
        didSet{
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    func getDouble(value: String) -> Double {
        return  Double(value)!
    }
}

struct DipoleSelect : View {

    @EnvironmentObject var property: Property

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Text("Select Frequency")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .fontWeight(.heavy)
            .padding()

            Picker(selection: $property.mhzValueIndex, label: Text("")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< property.frequencyValue.count) {
                    Text(self.property.frequencyValue[$0] + " mhz").font(.largeTitle).fontWeight(.semibold).color(Color.black).tag($0)
                }.font(.title)

            }

            Picker(selection: $property.mhzValueStepIndex, label: Text("")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< property.frequencyStep.count) {
                    Text(self.property.frequencyStep[$0]).tag($0)
                }

            }


            Text("You Selected \(property.frequencyValue[property.mhzValueIndex])\(property.frequencyStep[property.mhzValueStepIndex]) Mhz")


            Text("Total frequency: \(property.totalFrequency)")

       }

    }


}
```

Comment: I don't think `totalFrequency` is supposed to be cumulative like you have it here. Each `didSet` should be `totalFrequency = getDouble(value: frequencyValue[mhzValueIndex]) + getDouble(value: frequencyStep[mhzValueStepIndex])`

Comment: How you will calculate total frequency, depends on getDouble() method. I just tried to show a way to do that. You can just change the method.

Comment: Wow.  that looks complex... but I'll give it a go.. thank you very much for the amazing help. Cheers.